# Probability that an implication $P\rightarrow Q$ of events is true

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm reviewing a test for a mathematics competition, and have the question

> The probability that statement P is true is 62.5%, and the probability that statement Q is true is 60%. Determine the probability that P → Q is true.

I've looked everywhere for how to solve this, and can't figure it out. Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely have to assume that the two statements $P$ and $Q$ are independent. Otherwise the problem cannot be solved.

When is the implication $P\rightarrow Q$ false? It happens only when $P$ is true, and $Q$ is false. Thus
$$\text{Prob}(P\rightarrow Q\text{ is false}) = \text{Prob}(P\text{ is true})\text{Prob}(Q\text{ is false}) = 0.625\cdot (1-0.6) = 0.25,$$
and thus
$$\text{Prob}(P\rightarrow Q\text{ is true}) = 1-0.25 = 0.75.$$

Comment: I understand this a little bit, but I am slightly confused on what precisely the arrow means. Could you give an explanation for it? (in words)

Comment: @user324242 yeah, it means the event $P$ implies the event $Q$. If you haven't seen it before, I understand that it can look weird to talk about the truth or falsity of $P\rightarrow Q$, but here's how it goes: If both $P$ and $Q$ are true, then the event $P\rightarrow Q$ is true, i.e. if both $P$ and $Q$ are true, then it is true that $P$ implies $Q$. If however $P$ is true, and $Q$ is false, then it is *not* true that $P$ implies $Q$, i.e. $P\rightarrow Q$ is false in this case, which is what I use above. If $P$ is false, then $P\rightarrow Q$ is true no matter the truth or falsity of $Q$

Comment: For instance, is it true that "$1+1=3$" implies that "it is raining"? Yeah, any conclusion follows from a false hypothesis, so it is true. But anyway, you can see the a table of the truth values of the implication in the third figure here: http://www.sparknotes.com/math/geometry3/logicstatements/section4.rhtml but I recommend going more into logical operations. Any first year discrete mathematics course should do the trick. This page also explains some of it: http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/21.html

Comment: I understand it now, thank you! The links were helpful as well. :)